# what behaviour will <uses-library /> cause in the android market?

Tags: android, manifest

If I set  in the Manifest.xml and try to install the .apk with ecclipse, the install fails with a missing library error showing logcat. Thats ok for me as developer.

But how will be the behaviour in Google Play?
Simply writing a failure to logcat is not useful for normal users. Useful would be if an appropriate error dialog would appear, informing the user about the error, why and how to fix it (In this case, ideally a link to the missing app in Google Play, so the user can install the missing app easily)

Does anyone know, how exactly the  error is handled, if a user try to install the  .apk via android market (or other market places)?
Is there a way to costumise that handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [uses-library documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) you can use reflection to determine if a particular class is available. I haven't done this myself but here is a blog spot in which reflection is used to determine if the device support's live wallpapers [Using Reflection to test if an Android device is using 'Live Wallpapers'](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-app-optimization-using.html).

It must not be very hard to adapt it for other libraries.

Also, from API 7 there is a android:required value for  tag that allows the application to be installed from Google Play even if the library is not present in the user's device.

Hope this helps...

Comment: are you sure that this android:required flag set to false, will make the app show up in google play? The SDK docs are unclear about that.

Comment: @mradlmaier: "are you sure that this android:required flag set to false, will make the app show up in google play?" -- yes, that should work, barring a bug on the Play side of matters.

Comment: To tell you the truth I have try it with my application and it works as expected (I mean the android:required not the reflection) but from local installation NOT from Google Play. I assume it will work, otherwise why they put it there in the first place? But considering other Android documentation misleadings I understand your concerns, can't you try it and see?

Answer (score 3):

> But how will be the behaviour in Google Play?

The app will not show up in the Google Play Store, if the device does not have the firmware library you require. Hence, the user will not have an opportunity to install it.

This is covered in the [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) section of the docs.